# Arrastrar un view con la velocidad del gesto UIPanGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, xcode, objective-c

Tengo un metodo que me arrastra un view según deslizo el dedo sobre la pantalla. Para ello hago uso de `UIPanGestureRecognizer`.
En el metodo incremento la posición `x` del view punto a punto, pero me interesa moverlo según la velocidad con que muevo el dedo. Si deslizo despacio el movimiento si que cuadra si lo hago punto a punto pero si deslizo mas rápido los incrementos no se como hacerlos. He probado con el método `locationInView` o velocity de `UIPanGestureRecognizer` pero no acabo de implementarlo  bien.

```
CGPoint touchLocation = [panGestureRecognizer locationInView:self.view];
CGPoint velocity = [panGestureRecognizer velocityInView:self.view];

posX = posX + 1;
```

`self.view` seria la vista principal, `posx` es la posición de la vista que muevo según salta el evento.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es muy simple. Primero de todo creamos un `UIView` de ejemplo para ilustrar el resultado:

```
// Añadimos view de ejemplo
- (void)createView {

    // View
    UIView *draggable = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100.0, 100.0, 200.0, 200.0)];
    draggable.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [self.view addSubview:draggable];

    // Gesture
    UIPanGestureRecognizer *gesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(draggableAction:)];
    [draggable addGestureRecognizer:gesture];

}
```

Después, necesitamos el método que se ejecutará al hacer el 
`UIPanGestureRecognizer`:

```
// Acción al arrastrar la view
- (void)draggableAction:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

    // Cogemos la posición del gesto respecto de la view
    CGPoint touchCenter = [recognizer locationInView:self.view];

    // Modificamos el centro de la view
    recognizer.view.center = touchCenter;

}
```

De esta manera, al arrastrar desde dentro de la `UIView` se moverá junto con el centro del arrastre.

Comment: Necesito indicar la variación del movimiento en coordenadas relativas, no absolutas. Es decir si deslizo de un punto a otro saber la longitud en puntos deslizadas.

Comment: Tú has preguntado como mover una `UIView` con un `UIPanGestureRecognizer` y eso es lo que se contesta. Lo que comentas ahora no lo entiendo...

Comment: Necesito mover el UIView en las coordenadas X pero sumándole a la coordenada la longitud que me he desplazado ya que esta variable se la tengo que poner a una constante de una "constraint" de UIView, No me vale ponérselo en coordenada absoluta de pantalla.

Comment: Pero entonces eso es un problema de matemáticas y no de como hacer el desplazamiento. Coge el `touchCenter.x` y suma o resta lo que necesites.

Comment: Alfinal lo he solucionado utilizando los métodos  UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan y UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded. Gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: ¡Perfecto! Cualquier cosa avisa...